# Rails 4 undo "rails destroy MODEL"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, destroy, migrate

I was installing Devise into my Rails 4 application and misread the line in the wiki that talks about generating devise as a new model. I thought I needed to add it to each of my existing models. I used "rails g devise messages" to install devise in my messages model then realized that I was doing it wrong. So I used rails g devise messages to remove devise. This command got rid of my messages model entirely (the model that the whole app is built around). I have looked all over for how to reverse this but can't seem to find anything. I tried running rake db:rollback but it only rolled back my previous installs.

PLEASE tell me that there's some way to retrieve the model, views, controller and 300+ entries!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have any VCS on your app? (Git, SVN)

Comment: I don't. :( It's a solo project so I didn't think I needed it. I have learned my lesson. lol